# Erro com Php e Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

tenho a seguinte linha em um arquivo php

```
if(preg_match("!\oa!", $id)){
```

ate uns 2 meses atrás isso funcionava normalmente mas começou a dar este erro

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed:
>   missing opening brace after \o at offset

alguém sabe me dizer o que esta acontecendo ? utilizei alguns validadores de expressão regular online e não retornou erros.

Comment: ja tentou alterar para aspa simples?

Comment: ja tbm não resolveu

Comment: tente alterar `!` por `~`

Comment: O que aconteceu nesses 2 meses ?  Fez upgrade do php para outra versão?

Comment: Qual o intuito desse regex? o que ela deveria fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É provavelmente um *bug* na versão da biblioteca [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pcre.php) que você usa, atualize para a versão mais recente.

Como pode ser visto no [*changelog*](http://www.pcre.org/original/changelog.txt), item *32*:

> 32. Error messages for syntax errors following `\g` and `\k` were giving inaccurate offsets in the pattern.

O erro pode ser visto [**neste exemplo**](http://ideone.com/ROhTR7) que usa a versão 8.35:

```
echo PCRE_VERSION; // 8.35 2014-04-04

var_dump(preg_match('/\k/', 'foo')); 
// \k is not followed by a braced, angle-bracketed, or quoted name at offset 2

var_dump(preg_match('/\g/', 'foo')); 
//  a numbered reference must not be zero at offset 1
```

Uma alternativa é escapar `\k`, `\g` e no teu caso `\o` com uma dupla barra inversa `\\`:

```
$id = "\oa";

if(preg_match("!\\\oa!", $id)) {
    echo "Match!";
} else {
    echo "No match.";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/sPyYVe)</kbd>

Comment: resolveu com scape duplo ^^

Comment: so nao entendi o por que precisar de tres simbolos de scape

Comment: @JasarOrion É para especificar ``\`` literalmente. [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) tem mais algumas informações.